# Angular 2 : Pass string to ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template

I'm trying to pass a different template for each field of an array of string.

TS

```
export class MyComponent {
  fields = ['name', 'person.age', 'created_at', ...]
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
   <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="field">
       
   </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #name>
   Name template
</ng-template>

<ng-template #created_at>
    Created at template
</ng-template>

<ng-template #person.age>
     person.age template
</ng-template>
```

I obviously get an error because the `ngTemplateOutlet` expects a `TemplateRef` instead of a string. But how can I pass it a string dynamically to refer to the correct template? The error I get is:

> Error : templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

PS: There might be better solutions for this problem. Don't hesitate to share :) Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `*ngTemplateOutlet="field"` ?

Comment: Yes. Same problem... It is still recognize as a string rather than a templateRef

Comment: I have found a workaround : passing the reference from a fonction in TS :
@ViewChild('name') name: ElementRef;
getTemplateFromName(string) {
    return this.name
}

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplateFromName(field)"></ng-container>
<ng-template #name>
   Name template
</ng-template>

Comment: or you can use a child component to replace ng-container element

Comment: who is not cleared with the answers, read out here for more clarification https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Answer (score 26):

You can write it like such:

```html
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="{name, created_at, person_age}[field]">

   </ng-container>
</div> 

<ng-template #name>
    Name template
</ng-template>

<ng-template #created_at>
    Created at template
</ng-template>

<ng-template #person_age>
     person.age template
</ng-template>
```

This doesn't require child component.

Comment: Superb solution.

Comment: This is really awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Aha nice idea Razif

Comment: can be more simplified as 

`<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="{name, created_at, person_age}[field]">`

Answer (score 4):

See comment for the workaround to pass the reference using the typescript.
I just wanted to mention a second solution for those having the same problem : 
Use ngSwitch :)

```
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
        <div [ngSwitch]="field">
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'name'">
                   {{ field }}
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'person.age'">
                   {{ var[field] }} is my age
              </div>
              <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                   fallback
               </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create the templates in the parent component, and pass a list of templates as input to the child component :

```
<my-child [templates]="{'name': name, 'created_at': created_at, 'person_age': person_age}"></my-child>

<ng-template #name>
   Name template
</ng-template>

<ng-template #created_at>
    Created at template
</ng-template>

<ng-template #person_age>
     person.age template
</ng-template>
```

Then you can simply use the templates :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let f of fields"> 
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templates[f]">
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[Here is a stackblitz running code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49976019)

Comment: My favorite answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would you try this? (it works for me):

```js
export class YourClass {
  @ViewChild('ciao') ciao: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('ciao2') ciao2: TemplateRef<any>;
  
  fields: TemplateRef<any>[];

  constructor () {
    
    this.fields = [this.ciao, this.ciao2];

  }
}
```

```html
<ng-template #ciao></ng-template>
<ng-template #ciao2></ng-template>
```

Comment: They are null until the view is initialized. You must use `ngOnInit` to get the references.